# Powershell Rename a computer without a known local admin

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to rename 1000's of computers on a domain.  The problem is, the management account I have does have rights to change the name on the domain, but does not have access to the local machine to make the change.  The only account that is has local administrator rights on a workstation is the primary user of the workstation.  I have tested this in a test domain and it works perfectly, but in production the code below fails miserably due to the lack of rights.

Is there a way of running the script and getting the primary user of each machine, and then place it in to a variable for the -LocalCredential paremeter below to use?

The csv file has only two fields that is comma delimited.  The old computer name and the new computer name.

```
$list = Import-csv C:\temp\named.csv -Header oldcomputer, newcomputer
$domain = "domain.com"
$user = "administrator"

#Don't edit below this point
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $user" -AsSecureString
$username = "$domain\$user"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

foreach ($machine in $list)
{ Rename-Computer -ComputerName $machine.oldcomputer -NewName $machine.newcomputer -DomainCredential -LocalCredential machinename\someuserhere $credential -force -restart }
```

Comment: What does "primary user of each machine" mean? Generally in a domain, the `Domain Admins` group is a member of the local Administrators group on each machine. You can also use Group Policy to configure/enforce the Administrators group memberships on computers.

Answer (score 0):

- Regarding getting creds from target computers. I don't know of a way that would be possible. I think that would require hacking.
- What about a solution something like the following:

  1. a db containing three columns; oldname (varchar), newname (varchar), renamed (boolean)
  2. then have the Ps script run at user login, until all computers have been renamed
  3. The login script should run in user context -> meaning that the script would now be able to use the Rename-Computer under the admin users privilege.
  4. Have the script figure out the computer name when the user is doing a login
  5. Check the derived name against the db...if the found name has not been changed, use Rename-Computer cmdlet
  6. Update the tuple in the db, by setting the boolean to 1/true
  7. Message the user what was done and that a restart is necessary.....
  8. job done

I hope this helps....